# Gradle groovy how to keep comments and all formats in XML parser

Tags: xml, gradle, groovy, xml-parsing, comments

Gradle parse a XML file using groovy XML parser, for example,

```
<foo id="3">
    <!-- this is bar -->
    <bar id="5"
         attr1="10">
         attr2="20">
         <hello>world</hello>
    </bar>
<foo>
```

Parse the xml and write it out:

```
def root = new XmlParser().parse(new FileInputStream("/foo.xml"))
// add some nodes
groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(root, new FileOutputStream("/bar.xml"))
```

All the comments and line breakers are gone.
How to keep comments and all other formats with groovy XML parser?

I have looked at this:
[Groovy edit XML file, keep comments, line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744546/groovy-edit-xml-file-keep-comments-line-breaks)

How to import groovy.xml.*?  groovy is not recognized in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jdom2](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/), it will solve your issue

First, setup the dependency in your `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6'
    }
}
```

Then use this modified snippet :

```
def root = new org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder().build(new FileInputStream("/tmp/foo.xml"))
// add some nodes
new org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter().with {
    format = org.jdom2.output.Format.getRawFormat()
    format.setLineSeparator(org.jdom2.output.LineSeparator.NONE)
    output(root, new FileOutputStream("/tmp/bar.xml"))
}
```

Comment: I would like to try Java built-in xml and groovy xml API first. thanks.